# How do I insert data into my android app

Tags: android, sqlite

Like I'm trying to develop an application that already has data(paragraphs) . So the user will basically press a button to open up the specific texts.

From the tutorials I've done, I can only add them from the app, while I would want them to already come with the app. how would I go about this with sqlite or should I use something else?

Comment: if texts are not bulky use strings.xml else go for db but first option is more common approach

Comment: you can use SQLite to store that data if there a lot of it.
Or you can just put some text inside resources
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: @Rekmover: is it important to you to use sqlite?

Comment: How would I go about populating my database cause the data us bulky.

Answer (score 1):

In Android you can add prepared data to application in different ways. You need to choose the best way for your situation. For example:

1. You can prepare `sqlite` db file. Add in to application `assets` folder and after application will be first launched copy this db to internal `sqlite` db.
2. Add your text file to `assets` folder and the in application get data from it.
3. Add your file to `raw` `resource` folder, and then get it from there.
4. Or if your data is `String`, `int` ets. of `Array` you can add it to `resource` `values`

Comment: thanx alot. I'll prepare with sqlite , The data is alot so I think it would be better.

Comment: Yes, you are sure. For big data is better to use SQLite.